# Python date time without hyphens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would line to print today date but without the hyphens.

Right now if I use

```
today = str(datetime.now().date())
print(today)
```

I get this format:

```
2021-09-23
```

what I would like to see is this

```
20210923
```

I tried to use

```
.strftime("%YYYY %M %d")
```

But nothing, nothing seems to work. Can please somebody help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You figured out that you need to use `.strftime()`. You seem to have found the almost-correct format string for `strftime`. Did you do a quick web search to figure out if your format string is correct? https://strftime.org/ "Nothing seems to work" is a poor description of the problem you're having.

Comment: I think you are looking for `today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')`

Comment: as mentioned by @PranavHosangadi, you want %m instead of %M

Comment: alternatively, use `date` instead of `datetime`, like `date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is what you want:**

```
from datetime import date

print(date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

Output:

> `20210923`